# Using INavigationService without discarding ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, devexpress

Im using the `INavigationService` so i can navigate between two ViewModel like this:

MasterViewModel:

```
 public virtual INavigationService NavigationService { get; }
 //Command Navigate to SubUserControlView:
 NavigationService.Navigate("SubUserControlView", parentViewModel: this);
```

SubViewModel:

```
 public virtual INavigationService NavigationService { get; }
 //Command Navigate back to MainUserControlView:
 NavigationService.GoBack(parameter);
```

When i return to my `MasterViewModel` all my changes are discarded. How can i avoid that? I want to use the `SubUserControlView` to select a single value from a list and return it to `MasterViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `KeepAlive` property of the master *page* to `true`:

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication3.MasterPage"
      .... KeepAlive="True">
```

This should prevent a new instance of the `Page` from getting created each time it is navigated to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx.

This will also cause your view models not be re-created assuming you create these in the constructor of the pages.

Comment: i assume UserControls dont have this Property?

Comment: No. Just Pages.